# Python 2.7 for loop and not printing the right time

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, printing

Okay so i am writing a simple login system, here is the code

```
import time
for counter in range(5):
  username=str(raw_input("Please enter your username"))
  password=str(raw_input("Please enter your password"))
  if username =="bros10":
     print "",username,"entered"
     time.sleep(4)
     print "You got the username right"
     if password =="brosbros10":
        print "You got the password right"
        print "Welcome to the system"
        break

else:
    print "Try again"
```

And what happens when i run it is that it will print this bit print "",username,"entered" after i have entered the password
Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you want that to print before the password and it prints after? If so, the code is doing what you've asked of it. Try moving the `print` before taking the input for `password`.

Comment: you didn't say what you expect. what is your problem ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

```
print "",username,"entered"
```

To before this:

```
password=str(raw_input("Please enter your password"))
```

Now your program will ask for a username, repeat the username that is entered (and tell the user they got it right if they entered `bros10`), then ask for a password, then sleep 4 seconds.

Alternatively, you can place the `password=` line right before this one

```
if password =="brosbros10":
```

if you want it to ask for the password after waiting 4 seconds and repeating the user input.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to `print "",username,"entered"` before entering a password. Then it should look like:

```
import time
for counter in range(5):
  username=str(raw_input("Please enter your username"))
  print "",username,"entered"
  if username == "bros10":
     print "You got the username right"
     password=str(raw_input("Please enter your password"))
     time.sleep(4)
     if password =="brosbros10":
        print "You got the password right"
        print "Welcome to the system"
        break

  print "Try again"
```